# Best practices in regards to pass and deserialize data, when calling an API endpoint from a MVC-project?

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

In my application, I only show users their own data. For that, I need to know in the backend, which user is requesting data. I use the username for that and therefore, I need to send the username as part of the GET request.

The method in question, located in MVC-controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    ////Here, I pass username. ApiClient is a HttpClient and has a configured BaseAddress.
    var response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync("username?username=" + User.Identity.Name);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
    List<MatchViewModel> match = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MatchViewModel>>(result, options);
    return View(match);
}
```

Points of interest for feedback:

- Is this a good/safe way to communicate with endpoint? Couldn't a hostile party just change the `username` parameter by calling the API directly, and get another user's data?
- Does it make the method for confusing, that I instantiate a variable of `JsonSerializerOptions`?

Whatever feedback, advice or critique you might have, I am interested. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the heads up, I've tried to improve the title and a few points of interest for feedback. And thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few tips:

- respect `IDisposable` objects, apply `using` where necessary.
- if you encapsulating HTTP API logic into a helper class, do it completely
- exposing `HttpClient` outside isn't a good idea, what if you'll decide to change `HttpClient` for something else, either `HttpClientFactory` or something.
- `JsonSerializerOptions` can be instantiated once and reused.

Property getter/setter might help but why not expose the method that does exactly what needed? It would make the usage simpler like:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var query = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["username"] = User.Identity.Name
    };
    List<MatchViewModel> match = await ApiHelper.GetJsonAsync<List<MatchViewModel>>("username", query);
    return View(match);
}
```

The example

```cs
public class ApiHelper
{
    private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

    public static async Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(string method, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> query)
    {
        string queryString = new FormUrlEncodedContent(query).ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        using var response = await _client.GetAsync($"{method}?{queryString}", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
        using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(stream, _options).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

The method can be simplified using `GetFromJsonAsync` extension.

```cs
public static async Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(string method, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> query)
{
    string queryString = new FormUrlEncodedContent(query).ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<T>($"{method}?{queryString}", _options).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Finally, as here we have only one and the last `await`, then `async` state machine can be optimized out. There's no sense to launch the State Machine that has only one state, right? But be careful with this kind of optimization. Not sure - don't use. For example, it can break the method when the `await` is inside of the `using` or `try-catch` clause.

```cs
public static Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(string method, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> query)
{
    string queryString = new FormUrlEncodedContent(query).ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return _client.GetFromJsonAsync<T>($"{method}?{queryString}", _options);
}
```

Converting key-value pairs to URL-encoded query looks a bit tricky but `new FormUrlEncodedContent(query).ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` does exactly that thing.

I know that `ReadAsStringAsync` is `async` method but I know that content is already inside as I put the source directly to the constructor. Then the `ReadAsStringAsync` is completed synchronously here, then to save some resources I call `.Result` for the already completed `Task`, which isn't a bad practice. Only calling `.Result` for a not completed `Task` may lead to a problem with locked/deadlocked threads.

Never use `.Result` or `.Wait()` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` when you're not sure if the `Task` was already completed, use `await` instead (or always use `await`).

About `ConfigureAwait(false)` you may read [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) and [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html#avoiding-context).

Comment: Wow, that was a lot of great points and examples. Thank you so much for such elaborate and great feedback, really appreciate it!